# Repeating on adding data in Database

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem in my guestbook in php. After I fill up the guestbook, it works fine but when I look to my database, all the data I entered is repeated more than once.

**guestbook.php**

```
<table border="0" width="920" bgcolor="#1d1c1b" id="round"><tr><td>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr><br>
<td><strong><h2>SEACO's Guestbook</h2> </strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="addguestbook.php">
<td>
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td width="117">Name</td>
<td width="14">:</td>
<td width="357"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="40" placeholder="Enter your name here" required/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="40" placeholder="Enter your email here (Optional)"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Comment</td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="3" id="comment" placeholder="Your comment here" required></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="button"/> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset" class="button" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">

</table><br><center><strong><a href="viewguestbook.php"><button class="button">View Guestbook</button></a> </strong></center>
<br><br></table>
```

**addguestbook.php**

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="chess"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="guestbook"; // Table name 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$datetime=date("y-m-d h:i:s"); //date time

$sql="INSERT into $tbl_name(name, email, comment, datetime)values('$name', '$email', '$comment', '$datetime')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//check if query successful 
if($result){
echo "<br><br><center><font color='white' size='5'>Successful</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/cmark.png' width='40px'></center>";
echo "<BR>";

// link to view guestbook page
echo "<center><a href='viewguestbook.php'><button class='button'>View guestbook</button></a></center>";
echo '<br><br>';
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

**viewguestbook.php**

```
<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><strong><font color="white">View Guestbook</font> | <a href="guestbook.php"><button class="button">Sign Guestbook</button></a> </strong></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>

<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="chess"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="guestbook"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td><table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<tr>
<td width="117">Name</td>
<td width="14">:</td>
<td width="357" id="input"><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>:</td>
<td id="input"><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Comment</td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td id="input"><?php echo $rows['comment']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">Date/Time </td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td id="input"><?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
}
mysql_close(); //close database
?>

</table>
```

Comment: unset post variable after update..

Comment: Is the data actually saved more than once to your DB or it is only displayed like that?

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness it is saved more than once. around 6 times.

Comment: @user1844933 i don't get it.

Comment: @pingboo23 Are you using any JavaScript in there to make checks/submit form?

Comment: after update use unset($_POST['name']); and before update check isset($_POST['name']);

Comment: @user1844933 what do you mean by `update`? update code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['name'])) {
header ("Location: guestbook.php");
exit();
}
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="chess"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="guestbook"; // Table name 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$datetime=date("y-m-d h:i:s"); //date time

$sql="INSERT into $tbl_name(name, email, comment, datetime)values('$name', '$email', '$comment', '$datetime')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
unset($_POST['name']);
//check if query successful 
if($result){
echo "<br><br><center><font color='white' size='5'>Successful</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/cmark.png' width='40px'></center>";
echo "<BR>";

// link to view guestbook page
echo "<center><a href='viewguestbook.php'><button class='button'>View guestbook</button></a></center>";
echo '<br><br>';
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: this works fine but the problem is, it messes up the arrangement of the data in my database. rumbled data, not in order by id.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to execute your query 6 times  until you resubmit the form by reloading or any ajax request. If your query is executed then it should return true in $result. you can use exit() inside condition to check if it works and Try to check if form submitted by submit button  like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password="root"; // Mysql password
    $db_name="test"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="users"; // Table name

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];

    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server ");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $datetime=date("y-m-d h:i:s"); //date time

    $sql="INSERT into $tbl_name(name, email, comment, datetime) values ('$name', '$email', '$comment', '$datetime')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    //check if query successful 
    if($result){
        echo "<br><br><center><font color='white' size='5'>Successful</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='images/cmark.png' width='40px'></center>";
        echo "<BR>";

    // link to view guestbook page
        echo "<center><a href='viewguestbook.php'><button class='button'>View guestbook</button></a></center>";
        echo '<br><br>'; 
       exit();
    }

    else {
        echo "ERROR";
    }
    mysql_close();
    }
    else{
        echo "not set";
    }
```